# Decoding JSON feed that has an @ character - PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is my sample JSON:

```
[  
   {  
      "@attributes":{  
         "name":"Stack Overflow Movies ",
         "root":"http:\/\/www1.stackovermovies.com\/",
         "id":"1",
         "address":"Liverpool",
         "postcode":"PZ203434"
      },
      "films":{  
         "film":[  
            {  
               "@attributes":{  
                  "synopsis":"Description goes here.\r\n",
                  "poster":"http:\/\/www1.stackoverflowmovies.com\/posters\/HO00003702.jpg",
                  "cast":"Wayne Max",
                  "director":"",
                  "length":"125 mins",
                  "title":"X-Men (2016)",
                  "rating":"12A",
                  "release":"19\/11\/2016"
               },
               "shows":{  
                  "show":{  
                     "@attributes":{  
                        "date":"Sat 19 Nov",
                        "time":"17:00"
                     }
                  }
               }
        },
```

I tried to decode it:

The variable $feed contains the above JSON.

I tried to get the name attribute

`echo $feed->'@attributes[0]'->name;` but this is not working because of the @ character. Is there a workaround? I tried looking into CDATA but can't figure out if it's the right solution.

Comment: How did you get this json? @attributes and cdata tells me you are doing stuff with XML...

Comment: I used XPath to query an XML and outputted the result as JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `json_decode($json, true)` to get an array instead of an object. Then you can access your field like this:

```
$feed[0]['@attributes']['name'];
```

Comment: I get Warning: Illegal string offset '@attributes' and Warning: Illegal string offset '@name'

Comment: Added the json_decode - I get Notice: Undefined index: @attributes

Answer (score 2):

One way to access it is to provide a string value for the key in the object, like this:

```
$decoded->{'@attributes'};
```